# json call to MailChimp API not working

Tags: json, mailchimp

I'm calling the ListSubscribe part of the API with this json data:

{"apikey":"XXX-us2","id":"XXXXX"    ,"email_address":"joe@gmail.com","double_optin":false,"merge_vars":{"GROUPINGS":{"name":"Lectures","groups":"Lecture"}}}

and I'm getting back:

```
{"error":"\"L\" is not a valid Interest Grouping id for the list: members-announ
ce","code":270}
```

However, when I use id rather than name I get pretty much the same response (the docs say both are usable). I can get things to work if I leave out the GROUPINGS call.

The following is the enumeration of the groupings:
    result:

```
[{"id":11941,"name":"Lectures","form_field":"hidden","display_order":"0","groups
":[{"bit":"1","name":"Transit of Venus Wellington 12 June 2012","display_order":
"1","subscribers":1},{"bit":"2","name":"Transit of Venus Auckland 14 June 2012",
"display_order":"2","subscribers":1},{"bit":"4","name":"Lecture","display_order"
:"3","subscribers":0}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

just a quick test to do for you. 
I faced this problem yesterday with c#. My mistake was on the groupings structure.

Have you try this?

```
"merge_vars":{"GROUPINGS": [{"name":"Lectures","groups":"Lecture"}]}
```

I haven't tested because I don't need for my project: this is a simple reasoning consequent to my c# experience.

Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample json encoding that I have tested for listUpdateMember and works without issue.

Same layout as @Sandrous but I thought I'd demonstrate the approach for naming multiple interests in a group, along with the a full json encoding.

`{"apikey":"xxxx","id":"xxx","email_address":"xxx","merge_vars":{"GROUPINGS":[{"name":"Title","groups":"group1,group2,group3"}]}}`